# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch In Nested Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, nested-routes

Application Details: Rails 4 Ruby 2

I have a nested relationship, Stalls and Reservations.

when I try to create a new reservation from stalls I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Stall(#70127041150600) expected, got Reservation(#70127025144120)
@stall = Stall.find(params[:stall_id])
@reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)

** @reservation.stall = @reservation ** --> Highlighted Red in the error Message

respond_to do |format|
  if @reservation.save
```

The highlighted code is the code that is highlighted red in the application error message.

> **My Models are:**

```
class Stall < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
  has_many :reservations
end

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stall
  belongs_to :user
end
```

> **The create action in the Reservation Controller:**

```
class Stalls::ReservationsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @stall = Stall.find(params[:stall_id])
        @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
        @reservation.stall = @reservation

        respond_to do |format|
          if @reservation.save
            format.html { redirect_to @stall, notice: 'Reservation was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stall }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @stall.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
end
```

> **the routes.rb setup for this relationship:**

```
  resources :stalls do
    resources :reservations, controller: 'stalls/reservations'
  end
```

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

> **EDIT # 1: Adds Full Controller for Stalls:Reservations**

```
class Stalls::ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_reservation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /reservations
  # GET /reservations.json
  def index
    @reservations = Reservation.all
  end

  # GET /reservations/1
  # GET /reservations/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /reservations/new
  def new
    @stall = Stall.find(params[:stall_id])
    @reservation = Reservation.new
    @reservation.stall = @reservations
  end

  # GET /reservations/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /reservations
  # POST /reservations.json
  def create
    @stall = Stall.find(params[:stall_id])
    @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
    @reservation.stall = @reservation

    respond_to do |format|
      if @reservation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @stall, notice: 'Reservation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stall }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @stall.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /reservations/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reservations/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @reservation.update(reservation_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @reservation, notice: 'Reservation was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @reservation }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @reservation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reservations/1
  # DELETE /reservations/1.json
  def destroy
    @reservation.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reservations_url, notice: 'Reservation was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_reservation
      @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def reservation_params
      params.require(:reservation).permit(:stall_id, :user_id, :arrival_date, :arrival_time, :departure_date)
    end
end
```

> **this is the stack at the bottom of the error page:**

```
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"mCVcslrmH4mh6/kQieZf8gTmLBqEh5evS+jzwti1azx+UKMuO2v1WeeVWVsSZI4Zo9eunPJ2uHTAFHgrQPOYOA==",
 "reservation"=>{"stall_id"=>"",
 "user_id"=>"",
 "arrival_date(1i)"=>"2015",
 "arrival_date(2i)"=>"12",
 "arrival_date(3i)"=>"12",
 "arrival_time(1i)"=>"2015",
 "arrival_time(2i)"=>"12",
 "arrival_time(3i)"=>"12",
 "arrival_time(4i)"=>"23",
 "arrival_time(5i)"=>"31",
 "departure_date(1i)"=>"2015",
 "departure_date(2i)"=>"12",
 "departure_date(3i)"=>"12"},
 "commit"=>"Create Reservation",
 "stall_id"=>"1"}
```

> `LocalHost Server Output:`

```
Started POST "/stalls/1/reservations" for ::1 at 2015-12-12 16:31:25 -0700
Processing by Stalls::ReservationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mCVcslrmH4mh6/kQieZf8gTmLBqEh5evS+jzwti1azx+UKMuO2v1WeeVWVsSZI4Zo9eunPJ2uHTAFHgrQPOYOA==", "reservation"=>{"stall_id"=>"", "user_id"=>"", "arrival_date(1i)"=>"2015", "arrival_date(2i)"=>"12", "arrival_date(3i)"=>"12", "arrival_time(1i)"=>"2015", "arrival_time(2i)"=>"12", "arrival_time(3i)"=>"12", "arrival_time(4i)"=>"23", "arrival_time(5i)"=>"31", "departure_date(1i)"=>"2015", "departure_date(2i)"=>"12", "departure_date(3i)"=>"12"}, "commit"=>"Create Reservation", "stall_id"=>"1"}
  Stall Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "stalls".* FROM "stalls" WHERE "stalls"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Stall(#70127051519860) expected, got Reservation(#70127076366540)):
  app/controllers/stalls/reservations_controller.rb:32:in `create'


  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (3.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (50.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (36.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (81.1ms)
```

**No route matches [GET] "/stalls/1/reservations"**

**Full Trace:**

```
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Stall(#70127041150600) expected, got Reservation(#70127025144120)
```

The error message is saying it all. You are trying to assign a `reservation` to the `stall`, hence the error.

Change:

```
@reservation.stall = @reservation
```

To:

```
@reservation.stall = @stall
```

And, that should fix your problem.

Comment: So i thought about that earlier, however when i use that reservation.stall = stall it gives me a routing error uninitialized constant StallsController thanks for the prompt reply tho this has at least given me a new error to work with!! cheers

Comment: Can you show the full error trace? and the full controller code? yeah, its a different problem that we need to fix.

Comment: Somewhere you are trying to use `StallsController` but its not defined probably and hence the new error.

Comment: absolutly. give me a few min and ill update the question! Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the question with full controller and server output when trying to create the reservation.

Comment: please update your question with the latest controller code and the latest error stack trace and remove the old codes. It makes it difficult to follow the question with fixed information.

Comment: my apologies i will update this asap. thank you for the advice.

Comment: i just sorted out the problem, the issue was with the way the controller was listed in the routes.rb file. there was a type in the controller name, this is why it was not finding the controller. Thank you for all your assistance.

Comment: No problem. You are welcome. Glad to know that your problem is fixed :)